# C Char Array Creation Differences

Tags: c++, c, arrays, printing, printf

In C I've noticed that there are a few ways to declare a char array. What's the difference between:

1. ```
   char arr[10] = "abcdefghij";
   ```
2. ```
   char* arr2[10] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"};
   ```

   - `gcc` says I need the star after char in 2 and not in 1.
   - when printing 1 I can use `printf("%s\n", arr); and it prints abcdefghij@`
   - when printing 2 I have to use a `for` loop

Why are they different?

Comment: In case of second point `printf("%s\n", arr);` is undefined behaviour, as `arr` is not terminated by null character. You need one extra element to store this `'\0'` character. You might simply declare your character array as `char arr[] = "abcdefghij";` and issue is gone.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?  It's not legal C++ code.  Are you asking about the "too many initializers" error?

Comment: This not homework, I was just trying to do programming questions for interviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 1 is a char array, while the second is an array of arrays as "a" is in fact an array of 2 chars 'a' and '\0'

Comment: Well, the second is an array of pointers to arrays.  Its type is not `char[10][2]`.

Comment: It was an example. Indeed, only the 10 pointers to the inner char arrays are kept on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is a vector of char of 10 elements, and `arr2` is a vector of chars pointers of 10 elements

```
char arr2[10] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'};
```

It is equal `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this behavior, you have to know the difference between strings and chars. The former are created with `"` and can contain several chars, while the latter are created with `'` and represent only one char. Since you used `"` in your array initialisation, you created an array of strings, not chars. Now strings are represented via pointers to chars. Therefore the compiler wanted you to create an array of pointers to chars, instead of an array of chars.

Answer (score 0):

In the first one you are just declaring a string, but in the second one you are creating 10 pointers to 10 strings. As an example

```
char* arr2_0 = "a" ;
char* arr2_1 = "b" ;
char* arr2_2 = "c" ;
char* arr2_3 = "d" ;
char* arr2_4 = "e" ;
char* arr2_5 = "f" ;
char* arr2_6 = "g" ;
char* arr2_7 = "h" ;
char* arr2_8 = "i" ;
char* arr2_9 = "j" ;
```